# IP Change and Web Deploy has ceased functioning

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008, webdeploy

So I had Web Deploy set up for my ASP.NET application on IIS, and I was deploying from visual studio successfully for awhile. Eventually we upgraded our server and our IP address changed, nothing else on the server was changed, as they simply installed the entire image of our older server on the new one.

The only issue is suddenly, for some reason, web deploy has decided that the DESTINATION IS NOT REACHABLE. I have uninstalled and reinstalled web deploy, restarted the server several times, and restarted the services required for web publishing. Absolutely nothing has changed except for the IP address.

Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** you can get to the site via *IP address*, then it has nothing to do with the application/web deploy, which then it likely comes down to networking:

- DNS - critical for any IP addressing changes (including propagation time) and is likely the reason, based on that error message (not application level). You can do a quick check with `nslookup` and see if the result matches your new IP.

Hth.

Comment: Have done these checks, the domain is working correctly, the IP address is pointing in the right direction, I truly have no idea why it has stopped working.

Comment: Hmm..what about checking the [configuration of the new box](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes) - link has note on the error above. Hth...

Comment: What I've noticed though is if I navigate to https://mysite.biz:8172/msdeploy.axd on my dev pc, it throws a connection timed out error, but if I navigate to that on the remote pc itself, it pops up with a login dialog, meaning it is connecting to it. what could this mean?

Comment: @barnacle.m I know it's odd (because you've said you've been successful in the past), but that really sounds like either your local pc (or network) is blocking port 8172 _or_ the new environment of the new box is (the host network). That's why on the host itself it's fine, but not _through some other/external network_ . Hth...

Comment: well here's the thing, I've just tested some friends' servers with web deploy, and port 8172 is closed on theirs but it works fine. so I don't think port 8172 actually needs to be open... it can't be the environment of the host machine because the new server is in the same environment as the old one, in fact it's the same box, just reinstalled and given more physical resources.

Comment: Doozy...going back to the sole change then, IP address....any NAT, port forwarding? IMHO, I'm still on the network track because the box seems fine (you were successful on the box itself).